# Issues with Python socket module

Tags: python, sockets, irc

So I'm working on a Python IRC framework, and I'm using Python's `socket` module.  Do I feel like using Twisted?  No, not really.

Anyway, I have an infinite loop reading and processing data from `socket.recv(xxxx)`, where `xxxx` is really irrelevant in this situation.  I split the received data into messages using `str.split("\r\n")` and process them one by one.

My problem is that I have to set a specific 'read size' in `socket.recv()` to define how much data to read from the socket.  When I receive a burst of data (for example, when I connect to the IRC server and receive the MOTD.etc), there's always a message that spans two 'reads' of the socket (i.e. part of the line is read in one `socket.recv()` and the rest is read in the next iteration of the infinite loop).

I can't process half-received messages, and I'm not sure if there's even a way of detecting them.  In an ideal situation I'd receive everything that's in the buffer, but it doesn't look like `socket` provides a method for doing that.

Any help?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are already a bunch of solutions out there to do this of which Twisted happens to be the most versatile.

Comment: Why do you not want to use Twisted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really be using `select` or `poll`, e.g. via [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html) or [select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html), or twisted (which you prefer not to).

Reading from a socket you never know how much you'll receive in each read. You could receive several messages in one go, or have one message split into many reads. You should always collect the data in a buffer until you can make use of it, then remove the data you've used from the buffer (but leave data you haven't used yet).

Since you know your input makes sense line by line, then your receive loop can look something like:

- while true:

  - Append new data to buffer
  - Look for EOLs, process and remove all complete lines

Comment: I'm doing a similar thing; I'm splitting the input into lines and adding the lines to an input buffer.  I suppose I could use the existence of a newline to determine if the received data is 'complete'.

Comment: Yes, in your case newlines determine the end of a message

Answer (score 0):

Stream-mode sockets (e.g, TCP) never guarantee that you'll receive messages in any sort of neatly framed format. If you receive partial lines of input -- which *will* inevitably happen sometimes -- you need to hold onto the partial line until the rest of the line shows up.

Using Twisted will save you a lot of time. Better yet, you may want to look into using an existing IRC framework -- there are a number of them already available.